# How to delete array of element in array

Tags: php

I have two array. I want to remove if 2nd array exists in 1st array. For example

```
array1 = array ("apple","banana","papaya","watermelon","avocado");
array2 = array ("apple","avocado");
```

I want the output should be

```
Array ( [1] => banana [2] => papaya [3] => watermelon)
```

Here are some code that I'd tried.

```
foreach($array2 as $key){
    $keyToDelete = array_search($key, $array1);
    unset($array1[$keyToDelete]);
}
print_r($array1);
```

but the output is

```
Array ( [1] => banana [2] => papaya [3] => watermelon [4] =>avocado )
```

It only remove first element.

i also tried to do something like this

```
$result = array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($result);
```

but the output is it print all element in array1

Noted: I want the result need to be outside foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) should be work.

```
<?php

$array1 = array ("apple","banana","papaya","watermelon","avocado");
$array2 = array ("apple","avocado");

$array_diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($array_diff);

?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/q2XSS)

output will be.

```
Array ( [1] => banana [2] => papaya [3] => watermelon)
```

***You can also try below solution. result will be same.***. using [in_array](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) Check if first array value not in the second tester that value in the new array 'final_result' for results.

**in_array support (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)**

```
$array1 = array ("apple","banana","papaya","watermelon","avocado");
$array2 = array ("apple","avocado");

$final_result = array();
foreach($array1 as $value){

    if(!in_array($value, $array2)){

        $final_result[] = $value;
    }

}

print_r($final_result);

?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/D8SOC)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. but it doesn't work for me. I also tried that method before

Comment: I added the DEMO check. array_diff support - (PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7)

Comment: is there any way to do instead of using array_diff? my php version doesn't support it.

Comment: I added one more solution check

Comment: Glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of **[array_filter()](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-filter.php)** we can do it easily. It filters elements of an array using a callback function.

> `array_filter()` iterates over each value in the input array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

Here we have used `use($array2)` clause to access the external variable inside callback function. `$array2` is needed to filter out `$array1`.

```
$array1 = array("apple","banana","papaya","watermelon","avocado");
$array2 = array("apple","avocado");

$array1 = array_filter($array1, function($item) use($array2) { return !in_array($item, $array2); });

print '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hFN4Y)**

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to create a `set(associative array)` of elements in `$array2` and iterate over `$array1` and check if element in `$array1` exists in our `set` or not using `isset()`. We take advantage of the method/algorithm technique called [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

```
<?php

$array1 = array ("apple","banana","papaya","watermelon","avocado");
$array2 = array ("apple","avocado");

$set = [];

foreach($array2 as $element){
    $set[$element] = true;
}

$result = [];


foreach($array1 as $element){
    if(!isset($set[$element])){
        $result[] = $element;
    }
}


print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/PcS45

Comment: is there any tutorial to use hash in php?

Comment: @daffodil The associative arrays we use in PHP is hashing itself.